# Calculating indices for nested loops in CUDA

Tags: cuda, pycuda

I'm trying to learn CUDA and I'm a bit confused about calculating thread indices. Let's say I have this loop I'm trying to parallelize:

```
...
for(int x = 0; x < DIM_x; x++){
    for(int y = 0; y < DIM_y; y++){
        for(int dx = 0; dx < psize; dx++){
            array[y*DIM_x + x + dx] += 1;
        }
    }
}
```

In PyCUDA, I set:

```
block = (8, 8, 8)
grid = (96, 96, 16)
```

Most of the examples I've seen for parallelizing loops calculate thread indices like this:

```
int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
int dx = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

if (x >= DIM_x || y >= DIM_y || dx >= psize)
    return;

atomicAdd(&array[y*DIM_x + x + dx], 1)
```

`DIM_x` = 580, `DIM_y` = 550, `psize` = 50

However, if I print x, I see that multiple threads with the same thread Id are created, and the final result is wrong.

Instead, if I use this (3D grid of 3D blocks):

```
int blockId = blockIdx.x + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x
              + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z;

int x = blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z)
        + (threadIdx.z * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y))
        + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x) + threadIdx.x;
```

It fixes the multiple same thread Ids problem for x, but I'm not sure how I'd parallelize y and dx.

If anyone could help me understand where I'm going wrong, and show me the right way to parallelize the loops, I'd really appreciate it.

Comment: "when I print x, I see that multiple threads with the same thread Id" -- it's a grid, how do you imagine there wouldn't be threads with the same x index?

Comment: @talonmies: I understand that, so I'm confused how the first example is used to parallelize loops. Wouldn't it be wrong? Or am I not setting the blocks/grids correctly?

Comment: I don't understand what you are trying to ask here. It might be easier if you edit an [MCVE] into your question, explain what you expected the code to do and show the error you have implied exists in your question. Otherwise it is going to be very hard to provide you with an answer.

Comment: @AnderBiguri: That is why there is an atomic add in the kernel code.

Comment: @talonmies perhaps I went too far into guessing what OP wanted, I understand why that is needed there.

Comment: @talonmies, what I wanted to know was the right and most efficient way to  parallelize the 3 for loops given a 3D grid of 3D blocks. I apologize if I wasn't clear.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> However, if I print x, I see that multiple threads with the same
>   thread Id are created, and the final result is wrong.

It would be normal for you to see multiple threads with the same x thread ID in a multi-dimensional grid, as it would also be normal to observe many iterations of the loops in your host code with the same x value. If the result is wrong, it has nothing to do with any of the code you have shown, viz:

```
#include <vector>
#include <thrust/device_vector.h>
#include <thrust/copy.h>
#include <assert.h>

void host(int* array, int DIM_x, int DIM_y, int psize)
{
    for(int x = 0; x < DIM_x; x++){
        for(int y = 0; y < DIM_y; y++){
            for(int dx = 0; dx < psize; dx++){
                array[y*DIM_x + x + dx] += 1;
            }
        }
    }
}


__global__
void kernel(int* array, int DIM_x, int DIM_y, int psize)
{
    int x = blockIdx.x * blockDim.x + threadIdx.x;
    int y = blockIdx.y * blockDim.y + threadIdx.y;
    int dx = blockIdx.z * blockDim.z + threadIdx.z;

    if (x >= DIM_x || y >= DIM_y || dx >= psize)
        return;

    atomicAdd(&array[y*DIM_x + x + dx], 1);
}

int main()
{
    dim3 block(8, 8, 8);
    dim3 grid(96, 96, 16);

    int DIM_x = 580, DIM_y = 550, psize = 50;

    std::vector<int> array_h(DIM_x * DIM_y * psize, 0);
    std::vector<int> array_hd(DIM_x * DIM_y * psize, 0);
    thrust::device_vector<int> array_d(DIM_x * DIM_y * psize, 0);

    kernel<<<grid, block>>>(thrust::raw_pointer_cast(array_d.data()), DIM_x, DIM_y, psize);
    host(&array_h[0], DIM_x, DIM_y, psize);

    thrust::copy(array_d.begin(), array_d.end(), array_hd.begin());
    cudaDeviceSynchronize();

    for(int i=0; i<DIM_x * DIM_y * psize; i++) {
        assert( array_h[i] == array_hd[i] ); 
    }

    return 0;
}
```

which when compiled and run

```
$ nvcc -arch=sm_52 -std=c++11 -o looploop loop_the_loop.cu 
$ cuda-memcheck ./looploop 
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
```

emits no errors and passes the check of all elements against the host code in your question.

If you are getting incorrect results, it is likely that you have a problem with initialization of the device memory before running the kernel. Otherwise I fail to see how incorrect results could be emitted by the code you have shown.

In general, performing a large number of atomic memory transactions, as your code does, is not the optimal way to perform computation on the GPU. Using non-atomic transactions would probably need to rely on other *a priori* information about the structure of the problem (such as a graph decomposition or a precise description of the write patterns of the problem).

Answer (score 0):

In a 3D grid with 3D blocks, the thread ID is:

```
    unsigned long blockId = blockIdx.x 
             + blockIdx.y * gridDim.x 
             + gridDim.x * gridDim.y * blockIdx.z; 
    unsigned long threadId = blockId * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y * blockDim.z)
              + (threadIdx.z * (blockDim.x * blockDim.y))
              + (threadIdx.y * blockDim.x)
              + threadIdx.x;
```

Not the `x` you computed. The `x` is only the `x` index of that 3D matrix.

There is a nice cheatsheet [in this blog](http://www.martinpeniak.com/index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=288:cuda-thread-indexing-explained&catid=17:updates)

Comment: Thank you for your answer! What I really wanted to know was given a 3D grid of 3D blocks, what is the right way to parallelize the nested for loops.

Comment: @Kransa the way you are doing it is OK, you will have some slowness due to several threads writing in the same location, but otherwise seems good. Do you not get the correct results?

Comment: No, instead of 1 being added to a particular location, I get 900

Comment: @Kransa as talonmies pointed out, the code you have shown does the same in C and in CUDA, so you properly wrote the translation to GPU.